# java How to get chars after chars in a string in a http request

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm working on my own non-apache http server, but I finally come to the spot were I need to get variables from a string

To do that I created a method called GetArgument(String GetCmd, String arg)

GetCmd = the GET command (for example GET /blockip?ip=192.168.1.99)

arg = the argument that you need info about (for example 'ip' and that must return the ip above)

Extra arguments in one GET command are splitted by &

The current code for the GetArgument method is:

```
private static String GetArgument(String GetCmd, String arg) {
    String args[] = GetCmd.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        if (args[i].startsWith(arg + "=")){
            // Argument found
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But how do I do that?

Comment: I would consider using a HashMap<String, String> for that purpose. You can build it up once when processing the URL of the request, then use it to query parameters from your application as needed. Also note that your URL's may contain encoded characters. For instance, a space character becomes "%20". You'll need to properly decode those.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I found the answer:

```
private static String GetArgument(String GetCmd, String arg) {
    String args[] = GetCmd.split("\\?")[1].split("&");
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        if (args[i].startsWith(arg + "=")){
            String returnstring = args[i].substring(arg.length() + 1, args[i].length());
            return returnstring;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manipulate that much. your requirement can be fulfilled by the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("333 "+GetArgument("/blockip?ip=192.168.1.99&abc=xyz", "ip"));
}
public static String GetArgument(String GetCmd, String arg) {
    String tmp = GetCmd.substring(GetCmd.indexOf('?')+1);
    if(tmp.contains(arg)){
        return tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf(arg) + arg.length() + 1,(tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf(arg)+arg.length()+1).indexOf('&')>0)?tmp.lastIndexOf('&'):tmp.length());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer, but I found an easier way to do this (see my answer)